# How to read dates in R through numbers

Tags: r, date

I am still new to using R.
I opened a .dta file through R. I am asked to look for certain dates. However,
I don't know how to read the dates because they are written in large numbers. For example,
"17383" or "17384". How do I read them to find the dates I need?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question what the numbers in your file represent. Dates can be expressed as number of days since some fixed day. 
Suppose it is 1970-01-01, then you can use:

```
as.Date(17383, origin="1970-01-01")
```